# JSONSerialization with value types

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I would like to use Foundation's `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject obj: AnyObject, options opt: WritingOptions = []) throws -> Data` . However, I cannot figure out how to convert my value types into suitable reference types for use with that method.

For example, trying to serialise a simple String array fails because the method needs a reference type, not a value type:

```
root@1c6c66df21cf:/tmp# swift
Welcome to Swift version 3.0 (swift-3.0-PREVIEW-3). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> JSONSerialization.data( withJSONObject: [String]() )
error: repl.swift:2:48: error: argument type '[String]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'
JSONSerialization.data( withJSONObject: [String]() )
```

Casting does not work:

```
root@1c6c66df21cf:/tmp# swift
Welcome to Swift version 3.0 (swift-3.0-PREVIEW-3). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> let value = [String]()
value: [String] = 0 values
  3> let reference = value as! NSArray
reference: Foundation.NSArray = <extracting data from value failed>

Execution interrupted. Enter code to recover and continue.
Enter LLDB commands to investigate (type :help for assistance.)
```

I also tried to follow the examples from the [unit tests](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/swift-3.0-preview-3-branch/TestFoundation/TestNSJSONSerialization.swift#L610) for that version of core Foundation:

```
root@1c6c66df21cf:/tmp# swift
Welcome to Swift version 3.0 (swift-3.0-PREVIEW-3). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> let value = [String]()
value: [String] = 0 values
  3> let reference = value.bridge()
reference: Foundation.NSArray = <extracting data from value failed>

error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  (extension in Foundation):Swift.Array.bridge () -> Foundation.NSArray
```

System information for reference:

```
root@1c6c66df21cf:/tmp# uname -a
Linux 1c6c66df21cf 4.4.12-boot2docker #1 SMP Wed Jun 1 22:45:59 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@1c6c66df21cf:/tmp# swift --version
Swift version 3.0 (swift-3.0-PREVIEW-3)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.bridge()` is the correct approach. That error is specific to the REPL. It does not happen when compiling an entire file:

```
root@1c6c66df21cf:/tmp# cat test.swift 
import Foundation

let value = ["string"]
let reference = value.bridge()
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: reference)
print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)
root@1c6c66df21cf:/tmp# swift test.swift
["string"]
root@1c6c66df21cf:/tmp# swiftc -o test test.swift 
root@1c6c66df21cf:/tmp# ./test
["string"]
```